# Yslow: static components without a far future expiration date

Tags: http-headers, yslow

I am geting title message, all for external urls like plusone, google-analytics, adsense.
I guess I cannot do anything on this from my php scripts and settings.  Is it true?

Answer (score 2):

Correct. YSlow (just like PageSpeed, Web Inspector audits in Safari, Chrome Developer Tools audits) cannot know whether you can control the affected resources or not, so they will suggest that you apply every fix possible.